# How to add padding to centered background-image on html element

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

Right now I am doing this:

```
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(/icon.png) center center no-repeat;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-origin: content-box;
  padding: 100px;
}
```

The image is 3000x1500px let's say. I would like for it to be centered with 100px of padding, and for it to scale down the image so it fits in the center (vertically and horizontally). Right now the padding isn't doing anything and the image is being clipped for being too large I think. I also don't want to use an `<img>` element, only using `background-image` in CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider the background on the body element then you set another background on the html to avoid the background propagation and some unwanted effects<sup>1</sup>. Then you can adjust `background-size` to scale down the background.

Using `cover`:

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1200/1200?image=0) center/cover no-repeat;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-origin: content-box;
  background-clip: content-box; /*don't show on the padding*/
  padding: 50px;
  margin:0;
}
html {
 background:#fff;
 height:100%;
}
```

Or `100% 100%` (centring in this case will be useless)

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1200/1200?image=0) center/100% 100% no-repeat;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-origin: content-box;
  /*background-clip: content-box; no more needed*/
  padding: 50px;
  margin:0;
}
html {
 background:#fff;
 height:100%;
}
```

Also with `contain`

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1200/1200?image=0) center/contain no-repeat;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-origin: content-box;
  /*background-clip: content-box; no more needed*/
  padding: 50px;
  margin:0;
}
html {
 background:#fff;
 height:100%;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>The first code applied directly to html:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1200/1200?image=0) center/cover no-repeat;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-origin: content-box;
  background-clip: content-box; /*this will not work as expected*/
  padding: 50px;
}
```

Comment: @LancePollard what is the expected? there is no one that is at least close that we can rectify?

Comment: I don't want to clip the image in any way, or squish the image. I would like to scale it down, ideally without adding any content (i.e. any extra divs).

Comment: This one squishes it: "Or use 100% 100% (centring in this case will also be useless)"

Answer (score 0):

This updated css can fixed your problem (I am sure this will work for you)

```
html{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
body{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1200/1200?image=0) center center no-repeat;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-origin: content-box;
  background-clip: content-box;
  background-size:calc(100% - 100px) calc(100% - 100px);
  margin:0px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Wondering if you can do this without the extra div.